# How to check whether two conditions/rules match?

Tags: php, match, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I have some items and each item has a rule and I want to know which item matches another item.

Say item 1 has the rule 1 and item 2 has the rule 2:

rule 1:

```
z and d and (y or u) and j
```

rule 2:

```
u or ((e or z) and (d or y))
```

How to check whether or not these items match?

Comment: Try creating truth tables for each of the possible values and compare those.

Comment: It looks that z, d, y, u and j are your context variables.

Comment: @hakre and how to find them programmatically ?:-)

Comment: @AlexHowansky i added some code :-)

Comment: @csharpler how? can you give me an example or link to a tutorial?

Comment: @John Walker You basically choose every single combination (`2^<NumberOfVariables>`) and calculate the result with both of the rules. If all of them match, the rules are equal.

Comment: @csharpler would you like copy your comment as answer? i want to accept it :-) thank you for you hint!

Comment: @John Walker ok, I copied it now (sorry for the delay ;) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a Truth Table:
For every possible combination of the input variables, calculate the result for both of the rules.
If they give you the same values for every single combination, the rules are equal.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got from your question:

```
<?php
$rule1 = false;
$rule2 = false;

if($z && $d && ($y || $u) && $j){
    $rule1 = true;
}

if($u || (($e || $z) && ($d || $y))){
    $rule2 = true;
}

if($rule1==$rule2){
    echo 'These rules match.';
}else{
    echo 'These rules do not match.';
}?>
```

Comment: I dont have the variables $z, $d ... i could define them with value true but this wont make sense

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the outcome of each rule to variables:

```
$rule1 = $z and $d and ($y or $u) and $j;
$rule2 = $u or (($e or $z) and ($d or $y));
```

Both `$rule` variables are now either `true` or `false`.

```
$itemsMatch = $rule1 === $rule2;
```

Comment: I ask because in the end you need to pass the values to the ruler lib. That are the missing context variables.